# Water Hammer Issues

Tags: plumbing

I have a loose pipe that we cannot get to, it is behind a wall. It bangs loudly after any tap/toilet/water appliance is turned off/flushed etc. We put a water hammer arrestor by the washine machine, but it didn't really work as it happens with any faucet in the house.

I would appreciate some advice on how to stop it, since getting to the loose pipe isn't an option. Should water hammer arrestors be within 6ft of the problematic pipe?

Comment: Is it _behind_ a wall, or _in_ a wall? What type of wall? Do you have partial access? Details matter.

Comment: behind a plasterboard wall. Would an arrestor near as possible to the loose pipe be the best option?

Comment: @DanielNash If it's plasterboard, just open it up and fix the pipe.  You'll spend a fortune on dad-gadgets when you could fix this with two screws, one clamp, a cup of joint compound, and a half-cup of paint.

Answer (score 8):

It's likely that the offending pipe is just placed in such a way that even minimal water velocity changes cause it to move enough to bang into the wallboard or framing.

I suppose you could try to add arrestors to every water use-point in the house but that's likely to be a lot of work and not 100% reliable to fix the problem.

Your best bet is to just open up the wall, determine and fix the problem, and then refinish the wall.

Comment: If it's just drywall, sure, but it could be a nasty proposition if, for example, there is a very expensive tile job on the wall... and something similar on the other side as well.

Comment: If that's the case hopefully there is some way to access it from the other side but you're right, it could be a problem.

Comment: I have managed to find what i believe to be the offending pipe, or at least the start of it, and its going to be impossible to fix it to a wall/plasterboard to be honest. Should I get a plumber in to put a arrestor on the offending pipe?